# MS Access: My record keeps disappearing and appearing like a phantom

Tags: ms-access, record, subform

I am a beginner at MS Access, and I only learnt to put tables, queries, forms and vba codes via self learning. So please bear with me and my questions.

I had managed to put together a POS system using MS access. There is only one user for the system and it is not shared on any online platform to allow others to edit concurrently.

First, the user will choose the client from the "Customer" Form, which contains ActiveX Control command button for each client. The command button would open up the "Order" Form. 
Second, on the the "Order" Form, there is a Navigation Form to contain a variety of products (in ActiveX Control command buttons), which will input the orders into a SubForm. The user will then close the Form once completed using a command button.
The above mentioned steps will be repeated for every customer and additional orders.

I realised that my MS Access has a major problem. 
Sometimes, when the user double-clicked the client command button or click the same client command button after closing the form, there are 2 rows of blank records on the SubForm. If the first record is entered a certain product, and the subsequent records may be entered and the form is closed, this "first record" becomes a "phantom record".

This "phantom" record may disappear from the original client and appear in any client's order, especially those clients were subsequently double-clicked or click twice. Note that there is only phantom record, and there is no duplicated record, as the phantom record will appear and disappear. The main problem is that it keeps disappearing from the correct client, and appear under the wrong client.

I  cannot delete this "phantom record" from the SubForm, as the system will pick another first record of any client's order and it will become the new "phantom" record. Henceforth, my "report" at the end of day will contain error.

Please advise! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all review table structure, it should contain primary key. If the table doesn't have primary key, add autonumber field and make it as Primary Key. It will allow to edit/delete correct rows.

If the problem won't be fixed, it may mean that the database corrupted. [Here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html) is a good article about database repairing, see "Number of records varies, depending how the data is sorted" symptom.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had checked that my table did have a primary key and the database was not corrupted. It may be due to the vba I entered. I had explained the situation in another link. Please pop over to help if you can! Many thanks in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935464/ms-access-enter-a-specific-text-in-a-form-using-command-button-from-another-for