# MS Access: Enter a specific text in a form using command button from another form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, command, record

I would like to ask for your help on the following issue in MS Access.

I had created a form "CustomerListF", filled with command buttons for each client. For each button, I had created the following code:

```
Private Sub cmd_outlets_ABC_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "OrderFormF"
Forms!OrderFormF!Outlets = "ABC"
End Sub
```

The button would then open another form "OrderFormF" and enter "ABC" in the textbox named "Outlets". However, I realized the second line of code (Forms!OrderFormF!Outlets = "ABC") would always create a phantom record in my subform, which is located in "OrderFormF", and this record would travel to other clients' forms. This phantom record is usually created when the commandbutton is clicked twice (double clicks or subsequent clicks). It is a headache when the record starts to shift around.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcxB5.jpg)

I would like to seek your advice for vba code to edit the second line of code.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "phantom record"? What do you mean by "other clients' forms (I hope that you don't use separate forms for clients)? Why are you using multiple buttons where a combobox would suffice? Some screen dumps with clarification might help you 'cause it sounds your structure is op for improvement.

Comment: Phantom record is just a term I coined together as the record keeps traveling to other clients' subforms. I have a form "CustomerListF" that contains buttons for every individual customer. As I am using a touchscreen desktop, multiple buttons would be easier for my mother (she is the end-user) as it mimicked POS.

Comment: Might help if you would answer my other questions too ;)

Comment: What you could try is to disable a button as soon at it's clicked and enable it again once the order form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

This approach for filling the field in opened form is not good. OrderFormF initialization and second line of your code with assigning value to the field may be executed in different sequence, they are not synchronized. 
In order to avoid this, you should pass the argument to OrderFormF by another way. I would recommend to use `OpenArgs` parameter:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "OrderFormF",,,,,,"ABC"
```

And then in Load event of OrderFormF assign the value to textbox:

```
Me.Outlets = Me.OpenArgs
```

In this case the "ABC" value will be assigned to first row in the form or to new record, if form is empty. Before assigning you can select the row if you need to assign value not to the first row. Also this way will protect you against double click on button, Load event executed only once during first form opening

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. I had tried, but it did not work for me. There is no error with the code. I could open the form and the form does contain "ABC" in my Outlets field. However, it now causes 2 new records in my subform (which is inside OrderFormF), whenever I open the form. The first record is still a phantom record that travels to other outlets' subform. Any advice I can get for this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure that you deleted all rows like second one in your question, run search by all project for "Outlet" string

Comment: I always use a fresh app when I start, so there is no second row. When I followed your instructions, the second row started to pop out for every outlets. Even if I delete them, they will pop up again once I open the form for the same or a different client. If I use the phantom row, it will keep appearing in other clients' forms. Please advice.

Comment: Looks like you have some additional code, which creates additional rows, it's difficult to understand what's going on in the database without it. Try to run application under debugger step-by-step, it may help.

Comment: I think the issue may be using the subform. Is there anything else to replace the subform? I designed this access to be used as a touchscreen POS for my mother. I have a main form of customers in terms of command buttons, which will direct the user to another form. This form contains a subform to input customer's orders, a navigation form filled with command buttons for the products we sell, and some command buttons for numbers. The subform will record the orders in a table, which I created query and reports for printing.

Comment: My mother does not know how to use keypad, so I bought a touchscreen and only taught her to use the command buttons for her POS. Is there a way to replace subform to input customer's orders, and the orders be saved by table? Thanks!